# Grab data from JSON Array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

When I run an API request, I get the following data back.

How do I use PHP to grab the `subscriberCount` data from this?

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "statistics": {
    "subscriberCount": "80021",
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I have tried this, but no success:

```
<?php

$json = '{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "statistics": {
    "subscriberCount": "80021",
   }
  }
 ]
}';

$yummy = json_decode($json);

echo $yummy->subscriberCount;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found you need to remove `,` near `80021`:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "statistics": {
    "subscriberCount": "80021"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

And you may try with this code:

```
$yummy = json_decode($json);

echo $yummy->items[0]->statistics->subscriberCount;
```

Then your result will be ok.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to assist. I don't *think* this is where my issue lies. It's more in grabbing values from nested elements within the array itself.

Comment: You're a star, @Imran - many thanks for all your help :-)

Comment: I'm glad you got the solution. You may accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I will do - you're so fast I have to wait a few minutes :-D

Comment: You are most welcome @michaelmcgurk